# Best way to write a hash to a file

Tags: database, perl, file, hash

According to the dbmopen-docu this function has been largely superseded by the "tie" function.
I know the Tie::File module which accesses the lines of a disk file via a Perl array.
How would I do it if I don't need an array but a hash?

Comment: This entirely depends on what you want to achieve, and how much data is being stored. Can you add some more information?

Comment: I would be an alternative to (the superseded) dbmopen. In this actual case it's not much data.

Comment: By information, she meant: What kind of information? How is it used? How much exactly? Are there any constraints?

Comment: The dbm* functions aren't superseded if that's all you need. And they work with hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.24/Storable.pm):

```
 use Storable;
 store \%hash, 'file';
 my $hashref = retrieve('file');
```

or if you will need to store more data then [BerkeleyDB](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/BerkeleyDB-0.43/BerkeleyDB.pod):

```
use BerkeleyDB;
use MLDBM qw(BerkeleyDB::Hash) ;
use Storable;


my $env = BerkeleyDB::Env->new(-Home => $home);
tie %store, 'MLDBM', -env => $env;

$store{my_stored_hash} = \%hash;
```

Comment: "use Storable" link is broken. Perl people changed it to this: http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html

Answer (score 2):

The core-module SDBM_File could tie a hash to a file:

```
use Fcntl;
use SDBM_File;

tie(%h, 'SDBM_File', 'filename', O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) or die $!;
...
...
untie %h;
```

But: "...the length of a key, plus the length of its associated value, may not exceed 1008 bytes."

Answer (score 1):

Look at the standard AnyDBM_File module, and the other documentation it references, for some examples of using `tie` instead of `dbmopen`.

Answer (score -10):

To write a hash to file:

```
open(OUT,">myFile.txt");

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
   print OUT $key.",".$hash{$key}."\n";
}
close(OUT);
```

Comment: Please do not use bareword file handles, ever. They are a risk to the security and stability of your software and spreading them to newbies decreases the quality of perl everywhere. I will reverse my vote once you've made the change to use scalar file handles instead.

Comment: Which works fine until one of your keys has a comma in it.  And there's usually little point in sorting the hash -- just use each unless it really matters.

Comment: @Mithaldu, I won't be changing any code. If you're designing a mission-critical nuclear power plant (unlikely you'd be using Perl as it depends totally on one guy, a very talented enthusiast), I can see your point. If you're writing a piece of Perl, to get a job done as quickly as possible, I don't see what the problem is. Anyway, I never purported to give a complete answer - just an indicator as to how one might go about doing something. Therefore, you're neg rep is pathetic. I challenge you to provide a better answer.

Comment: @Porculus Obviously, one can print OUT in whatever format they so wish. Your neg comment is pathetic and probably symptomatic of some underlying issues. Got a better solution up your sleeve? If so, I'd love to see it.

Comment: "Do it better!" is the complaint of a child. It would behoove you to distance yourself from such things in the future. After all, you can identify a bad car even though you've never built one, can you? Furthermore, to answer your first question of why it is such a problem:

Comment: One of the projects i work on is a gene-engineering database, where you can imagine it is imperative that things work smoothly and exactly. It is done entirely in Perl. The Perl was atrocious when i arrived and rife with bugs, two specific ones (causing data file cross-corruption) were caused by bareword filehandle names matching. This happened because the people who built the first iteration learned Perl by googling and reading forums like this and copying off the examples. They were not even aware there were better ways to do it and too busy to just go and search for them on a whim.

Comment: As such: Realize that while you may not be writing for a nuclear power plant here; you are sowing seeds for people that might go on to work in a power plant. As such any code you ever publish should be the best you can produce. PS: Since i know you'll scoff at all i wrote until your challenge is met, please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292780/best-way-to-write-a-hash-to-a-file/4292880#4292880 It provides the same functionality your answer had (via Data::Dumper) by converting a hash to a writable string, in an unambiguous way that can even be reimported.

Comment: @Mithaldu. You still haven't contributed anything positive to this thread. Jira's answer was accepted and is probably the cleanest solution sofar, albeit it requires an include.

Comment: @Mithaldu: Srsly mate, Perl will never be allowed anywhere near mission-critical systems such as aviation/space, nuclear systems and medical devices. I love Perl, but it just doesn't have the assurances. Anyway, all this is moot.

Comment: You do realize that Data::Dumper, Storable and JSON are the same exact thing safe for implementation details? They're all at the core serialization modules which is exactly what OP needs. Then, the upvotes my comments throughout this questions received are not indicator of positive contribution? Really? Lastly: Perl has been used for medical devices as well: http://perlisalive.com/articles/8 PS: Using "includes", i.e. using modules from CPAN is good, not bad.

Comment: My suggested solution works. It's just a pity it took you several bitchy responses to make a suggestion. Anyway, the OP has a solution now. Also, the example you gave doesn't give any indication about mission critical standards adhered to. Perl cannot be used in mission-critical applications. Have you any experience working on mission-critical applications yourself? You said you work on gene engineering for which I'm aware there are several useful Perl modules. Anyway, printing a hash isn't exactly the most pressing issue known to man. Cheerio now,